# Summation of $n^2x^n$ terms

Tags: calculus

How does one evaluate the following summation of $n^2$ terms by $x^n$ terms.
I have tried to do it, but couldn't figure it out as it is not the same as summing up $nx^n$ terms.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 x^n$$

Comment: You seem to know how to calculate $\sum nx^n$. How would you do that? Chances are, the technique you used can, with some minor tweaking, help you calculate $\sum n^2x^n$

Answer (score 5):

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$

Differentiating (and multiplying with $x$)we have,

$\displaystyle \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^n$

Differentiating(and multiplying with $x$) we have,

$\displaystyle \frac{[(1-x)^2(1)-(x)2(1-x)(-1)]x}{(1-x)^4}= \frac{x^2+x}{(1-x)^3}=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^2x^n$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: 
$$
x \, \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\sum x^{n+1} = x \, \frac{d}{dx} \sum (n+1) \, x^n = x \, \sum n(n+1) \, x^{n-1} = \sum n^2 x^n + \sum n x^n
$$

Comment: +1 for compact presentation

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$ ((x^n)'\cdot x)'\cdot x =n^2 \cdot x^n $$